# SharePoint 2013 unable to add or edit pages after visual upgrade to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

My site collection is throwing error while creating or editing pages after performing visual upgrade from 2010 to 2013 mode. I am able to create/edit, sub sites, lists, but not publishing pages. Unable to navigate to "Page Layouts and Site Templates" page from site settings. I am able to add/edit pages from sub site as long as I do not activate Publishing feature on the sub site. Once the publishing feature is activated the problem starts.

Error while creating a page:

Sorry, something went wrong 
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Technical Details

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: 
Error from Logs:

Name=Request (POST:https://.com:443/sites//_layouts/15/CreatePublishingPageDialog.aspx?IsDlg=1)

Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0e.t|pingfederatests|, ClaimsCount=58

Site=/sites/

Spent 0 ms to bind 29925 byte file stream

WARNING: Cannot change FormContext.FormMode to [Invalid] because it is already set to [New]

WARNING: Cannot change FormContext.FormMode to [Invalid] because it is already set to [New]

Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 agb9s,50 7fz4,0 7fz4

Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:https://.com:443/sites//_layouts/15/CreatePublishingPageDialog.aspx?IsDlg=1)). Execution Time=81.1101690298627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by updating the default page layout of the site collection using PowerShell. Followed the solution from http://www.justinkobel.com/post/2014/01/02/Error-in-SharePoint-Publishing-Sites-For-Default-Pages

Add-PSSNapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$site = Get-SPSite https://sitecollectionURL
$publishingSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($site)
$publishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($site.RootWeb)
$pageLayout = $publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts() | ? { $_.Name -eq "BlankWebPartPage.aspx" }
$publishingWeb.SetDefaultPageLayout($pagelayout, $true)
$publishingWeb.Update()